# Which.max Produced Same Result

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

So I know to determine the first occurrence of a specific element in each row you use the apply function with which.max or which.min. Here is the code that I am using right now.

```
x <- matrix(c(20,9,4,16,6,2,14,3,1),nrow=3)
x
apply(3 >= x,1,which.max )
```

This produces and output of:

```
[1] 1 3 2
```

Now when I try to do the same thing on a different matrix "x2"

```
x2 <- matrix(c(3,9,4,16,6,2,14,3,1),nrow=3)
x2
apply(3 >= x2,1,which.max )
```

The output is the same;

```
[1] 1 3 2
```

But for "x2" it is correct because the "x2" matrix's first row does have a value less than or equal to three.

Now my question  which is probably something simple is why do the apply functions produce the same thing for "x" and "x2". For "x" below I would want something like:

```
[1] 0 3 2
```

Or maybe even something like this:

```
[1] NA 3 2
```

I have seen questions on stack overflow before on which.max not producing NAs and the answer was to just use the which() function, but since I am using a matrix and I want the first occurrence I do not have that luxury... I think.

Comment: `which.max` applied to a logical vector returns the index of the first TRUE; or 1 if there are no TRUE values; or nothing of there are only NA values, as described in the docs. Not sure what you're after here.

Comment: @akrun that is exactly what I was looking for. Do you mind explaining what ";" do in R functions?

Comment: I think I am wrong there. May be `x[x>3] <- -999; max.col(x)*!!rowSums(x>0)`

Comment: Both seemed to work, why did you think you were wrong?

Comment: And what is the "!!" for

Comment: It was returning the value instead of the index.  Corrected and posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could replace the values in 'x' that are >3 with a very small number, for e.g. -999 or the value that is lower than in the minimum value in the dataset.  Get the index of the replaced vector with `which.max` and multiply with a logical index to take care of cases where there are only negative values. i.e. in the case of 'x', the first row is all greater than 3.  So by replacing with `-999`, the `which.max` returns `1` as the index but we prefer to have it `NA` or `0`.  By using `sum(x1>0`, the first row will be '0' and negating (`!`), it converts to `TRUE`, negate once again and it returns FALSE.  Multiplying the logical index coerces to binary (0/1) and we get the '0' value for the first case.

```
  apply(x, 1, function(x) {x1 <- ifelse(x>3, -999, x)
                   which.max(x1)*(!!sum(x1>0))})
  #[1] 0 3 2

  apply(x2, 1, function(x) {x1 <- ifelse(x>3, -999, x)
                      which.max(x1)*(!!sum(x1>0))})
  #[1] 1 3 2
```

---

Another option is using `max.col`

```
 x1 <- replace(x, which(x>3), -999)
 max.col(x1)*!!rowSums(x1>0)
 #[1] 0 3 2

 x2N <- replace(x2, which(x2>3), -999)
 max.col(x2N)*!!rowSums(x2N>0)
 #[1] 1 3 2
```

Or a slight modification would be

```
 indx <- x*(x <=3)
 max.col(indx)*!!rowSums(indx)
 #[1] 0 3 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What is the !! used for in R

Comment: @AdamWarner If you look at the `rowSums(indx)` the first value is `0` ie. all the value in that row is greater than 3.  We need to create a logical TRUE/FALSE or a binary vector instead of `0 3 3`.  One way is to negate (`!`), so that 0 become TRUE and all other FALSE.  Negating again gives TRUE changed to FALSE and viceversa.  This when we multiply, it is coerced to binary `0/1`

Answer (score 0):

Put a column in front of '(3>=x)' that is Infinity, if and only if all entries in the corresponding row of 'x' are larger than 3, and otherwise NaN. Then apply 'which.max' rowwise, and finally subtract 1, because of the extra column:

```
x <- matrix(c(20,9,4,16,6,2,14,3,1),nrow=3)
a <- (!apply(3>=x,1,max))*Inf

apply( cbind(a,3>=x), 1, which.max ) - 1
```

This gives '0,3,2' 'which.max' is applied to the extended matrix

```
> cbind(a,3>=x)

       a      
[1,] Inf 0 0 0
[2,] NaN 0 0 1
[3,] NaN 0 1 1
```